# ReferenceError: not defined with activeX

Tags: javascript, xml, activexobject

what does it mean to get this error:

```
ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

here is my code:

```
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    varFileObject = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\LogFile.txt", 8, true,0); // 8=append, true=create if not exist, 0 = ASCII
    newObject.write(XML.innerHTML);
    newFileObject.close();
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: ActiveX only works in IE.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Why are you using ActiveX when HTML5 is so much better? :-)

Comment: lol i was looking at what is broken with old code written well before by someone else.. was just wondering why it was broken.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the security setting of your browser is blocking it.

If you try IE6 the code should work.  You have to use a dead browser because the new browsers block it from working as part of a killbit fix that Microsoft did to fix a security issue.

Comment: All versions of IE support ActiveX, not just IE6 (which is dead).  You can change the security settings to allow it.

Comment: this code was killed purposefully by microsoft see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/27092b49-7d3e-4d86-9ffb-223a26037c3f