# Error Activexobject is not defined

Tags: javascript

this is my code

```
function writeToFile(){
                var data= { srcimg :document.getElementById("ClonedElementX").src }
                alert(data.srcimg);
                 var fso = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                 var fh = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\Users\\Bhargavi\\workspace\\HTML\\drag&drop\\parse", 8);
                 fh.WriteLine(data.srcimg);
                 fh.Close(); 
        }
```

Error is : Uncaught reference error  Activexobject is not defined. how to rectify that

Comment: Use Internet Explorer (I never thought I would say that).

Comment: This was a supported thing in IE and also a security issue. Javascript should not be able to access directly to your hard disk.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362861/referenceerror-not-defined-with-activex

Comment: for IE also its not working

Comment: @Bhargavi - As I told you its a security issue why you want to do that?

Comment: ok tell me some other functions that help to write the file using javascript

Comment: The point that @imsiso was trying to make is that you shouldn't be attempting to access the local hard disk in the first place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined Error in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927038/uncaught-referenceerror-activexobject-is-not-defined-error-in-chrome)